How to mask a multi-head attention layer?
I'm trying to make a Transformer model that could recibe sequences of a variable lenght. But I can't
I tried this:
def transformer_model(input_shape, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dropout_rate, output_shape):
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

    mask = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.cast(x!=-99, dtype=tf.float32))(inputs)

    x = PositionalEncoding(input_shape[0], d_model)(inputs) 


    for i in range(num_layers):
        att = keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=d_model)(x, x, attention_mask=mask)
        att = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(att)
        att = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x + att)
        
        ress = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=d_model, activation='relu')(att)
        ress = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(ress)
        x = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(ress + att)

    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=output_shape)(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

It can be created, but when I use the model, this error appears:
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Softmax.call().

Dimensions must be equal, but are 6 and 120 for '{{node functional_85_1/multi_head_attention_173_1/softmax_171_1/add}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT](functional_85_1/multi_head_attention_173_1/transpose_2, functional_85_1/multi_head_attention_173_1/softmax_171_1/mul)' with input shapes: [1,6,120,120], [1,6,120,22,1].

Arguments received by Softmax.call():
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 6, 120, 120), dtype=float32)
  • mask=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 6, 120, 22, 1), dtype=bool)

How can I create a good mask?

Your are facing an issue related to shape mismatch.Specifically, the mask has dimensions (1, 6, 120, 22, 1), but the attention scores have dimensions (1, 6, 120, 120) ,To resolved this issue you can use tf.expand_dims to matches the expected shape .
